# Output results as csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Can you help me output the result to a csv file?

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime

response = requests.get('https://publicacionexterna.azurewebsites.net/publicaciones/prices')
myroot = ET.fromstring(response.content)

print(f"Place_id\tItem\tPrice\tDate")

for x in myroot.findall('place'):
         place_id = x.get('place_id')
         item = x.find('gas_price').attrib['type']
         price = x.find('gas_price').text
         today = datetime.date.today()
         print(f"{place_id}\t{item}\t{price}\t{today}")
```

thanks for your help

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

- Create a header list Create row list
- Add Each row as a list to dataList
- Open file and Write headerlist
- Writerow data to the opened file

`Main.py` :

```
import csv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime

response = requests.get('https://publicacionexterna.azurewebsites.net/publicaciones/prices')
myroot = ET.fromstring(response.content)

print(f"Place_id\tItem\tPrice\tDate")

headerlist = ["Place_id","Item","Price","Date"]  # added a header list

dataList = [] # empty list to place each row

for x in myroot.findall('place'):
    rowList =[] # empty row list to add individual data
    
    place_id = x.get('place_id')
    rowList.append(place_id)  # append place id
    item = x.find('gas_price').attrib['type']
    rowList.append(item) # append item
    price = x.find('gas_price').text
    rowList.append(price) # append price
    today = datetime.date.today()
    rowList.append(today) # append today
    dataList.append(rowList) # append the entire row as a lit to data list


with open('example.csv', 'w', newline='') as file: # open csv file 
      write = csv.writer(file)
      write.writerow(headerlist) # write header data
      write.writerows(dataList) # write each row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to build a list of dictionaries, and pass it to a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{
  "place_id": x.get('place_id'),
  "item": x.find('gas_price').attrib['type'],
  "price": x.find('gas-price').text,
  "today": datetime.date.today()
}, for x in myroot.findall('place')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("Output_csv_file.csv")
```

The downside is that you would have to install a third party library (pandas), but this an easy, high-level solution, I hope it helps!